# Progressive Web App - service worker update

Tags: service-worker

Today I added few more features to my PWA and created a production build. But when I tried to test it on the production environment, my service worker file was not updated. Hence it refers my old versions of - index.html, main.js, main.css and polyfill.js files. It was weird completely

I am having a version number on my service worker file and I changed it before taking LIVE (run on number)… As per the standard if the sw detects a byte change from the installed version, then it will download and install the newer version which was not happening in my case…

Any suggestion… Thanks in advance!

regards,
Mano

Comment: are you saying the service worker file is not updated or the files in your cache are not updated?
If the later you need to add the code to manage what gets cached and for how long. You can use the install and activate event handlers to manage things like previous version's caches.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Chris...

Comment: Actually my service worker installed on my browser was not updated, hence all the PWA core files as well. I developed PWA using Ionic framework and my SW will cache the files - main.css, main.js, pollyfill.js and index.html. Since my new SW was not updated my new features are not updated on my app now. In service worker "install" event I called e.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()) and in the "activate" event I am clearing the older cache and also calling self.clients.claim() to reclaim all the opened clients immediately. But its not happening in my case...

Comment: just curious, are you caching your service worker file?
also do you have a long Cache-Control header applied or is this localhost?

Comment: No I am not caching service worker file. Also I have not mentioned any cache control header. But even if we mention one SW will look for an update and it will install the new version of SW which will update my cache....am I right?

Comment: no, your cache is managed programmatically, not automatically. Just because you update the sw does not update what is cached. If that were the case then cache would not give you an advantage in loading or cause excessive traffic as you precache assets that have not changed, etc.